# Angular Count Becomes 0 When Page is Refreshed

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my code, I have a page where the user can scan some labels and gets add to a list. Every time the user scan a label, total and package count above the list gets updated. But when I refresh the page, the counts become 0 as if there is no label on the list. Here is my code. What should I do?

HTML:

```
                        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                            <span class="pr-4">{{'Paket : ' + packageCount }}</span>
                            <span>{{'Adet : ' + totalCount }}</span>
                        </div>
```

TS:

```
constructor(){
this.calculateRemainingValue();
}
  addPackage(response: IKoli, barcodeNumber: string): boolean {
    this.calculateRemainingValue();
    this.isSaved = false;
    this.fg1.reset();
    return true;
  }
      calculateRemainingValue() {
        if (this.dataSource.data) {
          this.packageCount = this.dataSource.data.length;
          let totalWeight = 0;
          this.dataSource.data.forEach((x) => (totalWeight += Number(x.PaketAdedi)));
          this.totalCount = totalWeight;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Where do you store the count? JavaScript has to be completely reevaluated in each page reload and all variables are initialized. You can store such values in your browser (e.g. local storage) or on the server.

Answer (score 0):

How I know this is normal behaviour of angular.

You must save the counter in some place, for example database or you could save it as cookie or save it in localStorage/sessionStorage.

Hope I helped you!